# Wait between running functions in recursive loop

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I created a recursive loop to delete items in a SharePoint list with SPServices. I put a timeout in for 5 seconds; however for some reason it only deletes 2 items at a time, and then executes the wait instead of deleting the batch, and then repeating the function.

Please find my code below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $intStart = 1;
        $intCount = 10;
        $intEnd = 40;

        $("input[class='buttonpush']").click(function () {
            var looper = function () {
                if ($intStart < $intCount && $intStart < $intEnd) {
                    $().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({
                        webURL: "http://widgettest",
                        listName: "TestList",
                        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>" + $intStart + "</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>" + $intCount + "</Value></Lt></And></Where></Query>",
                        batchCmd: "Delete",
                        valuepairs: [],
                        debug: false,
                        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                            $intStart = $intStart + 5;
                            $intCount = $intCount + 5
                            setTimeout(looper, 5000);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else { 
                }
            }
            looper();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where `looper()` is executed the first time.  This will also only ever work once because your counter variables are undeclared globals and are not reinitialized when the button is clicked.

Comment: Please describe what you expect this code to do.  How many iterations should it be doing?

Comment: jfriend00, I see what you are saying about the variables... but for one reason or another it is working for me. I would expect it do as many iterations as would meet the if statement requirements. So if I wanted to delete 20 items, and I am upping the value by 5 each time it should take start + 3 iterations to say delete 20 items.

Comment: Also, you should change `"input[class='buttonpush']"` to `"input.buttonpush"` or just `".buttonpush"`.  Much simpler for the selector engine.

Comment: I repeat my question.  Where is `looper()` ever called?  If it is ever working for you, then you have not included all the relevant code in your post.  What you have here will never execute `looper()` even once.

Comment: If the loop is starting (which won't happen from the code you've posted), then the reason for it to stop prematurely would be because it runs into some sort of error and `completefunc` is not executed as planned.

Comment: Looper is calling itself in the completefunc line of the SPServices call. `completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                            $intStart = $intStart + 5;
                            $intCount = $intCount + 5
                            setTimeout(looper, 5000);`

Comment: But who calls `looper()` the first time?

Comment: WOW! Complete space cadet moment! Okay, there is a call to looper(); outside of the if statement. I've updated the code above to reflect that.

Comment: Okay, cannot edit my comment... what I meant to say was outside of the whole function, and not the if statement since that is also in the variable.

Comment: Why are you defining looper fresh each buttonpush?  Wouldn't it make sense to just define it once as a function and have that function be called each time?  Also, my guess would be that you've somehow miswritten the CAMLQuery - it looks like that's where you have the logic for what to do each cycle (which seems to be your problem) and it also looks like it would be very easy to miswrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that you show the initial call to `looper()`, there does not appear to be anything wrong with the logic.  `looper()` should run 8 times until `$intStart` is equal to 41.  These are the reasons that you might not get as many successive runs of looper() as you are expecting:

1. You get an error from `$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems()` and `completeFunc` is not executed like you are expecting.
2. Something else in your code is manipulating the values of the global variables `$intStart`, `$intCount` or `$intEnd` so they get changed accidentally while you are running and thus the loop doesn't run as many iterations as expected.
3. You get a javascript exception somewhere during the running of `looper()` that causes execution to stop.

To debug this, just put a unique `console.log()` statement right before the call to `$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems()` and another one in the `completeFunc` so you can tell exactly how far it's getting before stopping.

Some other observations on the code:

1. `$intStart` is always less than `$intCount` since it starts less and both are incremented by 5 so you don't need that part of the `if` statement.
2. It is not customary to preceded javascript variables with a `$` sign unless you are connoting some special kind of variable.  That is not the case here and just impedes the readability of the javascript to someone familiar with javascript.
3. Your variables `$intStart`, `$intCount` or `$intEnd` should probably not be global variables and in all cases should not be implicitly declared or accidentally declared globals.  If you mean for them to be globals, then declare them as globals in the global scope using `var`.  If you mean for them to be local to some scope, then declare them in that scope.
4. Because your variables are global and are only initialized one at `document.ready()` time, your button push will only work the first time.  It will never do anything when pushed a second time.
5. Your code is not protected from the user pushing the button again while `looper()` is running (this will cause duplicate requests to be launched).

Here's what your CAMLQuery will be the first two times:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Gt>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                <Value Type='Counter'>1</Value>
            </Gt>
            <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                <Value Type='Counter'>10</Value>
            </Lt>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>"    

<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Gt>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                <Value Type='Counter'>6</Value>
            </Gt>
            <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                <Value Type='Counter'>15</Value>
            </Lt>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>"
```

This doesn't look correct to me.  The first time, you're asking to process > 1 && < 10.  The second time, you're asking to process > 6 && < 15.

Shouldn't the second time be > 9 && < 18 to get new ones that weren't already processed?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help. I will make some changes, and see where that gets me.

Comment: should actually run 8 times - 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36.  Also, the $ is generally used to denote JQuery variables (though in this case, admittedly, the OP doesn't appear to be using them as such).

Comment: @BenBarden - Yes, exactly what I said was: "It is not customary to preceded javascript variables with a `$` sign unless you are connoting some special kind of variable."  And, there is no special kind of variable being used here (like jQuery) so the `$` is not customary.  You are correct on the 8 iterations.

Comment: So I made a few changes... 1) I created the variables using `var`; however, then it stopped looping. 2) I added `console.log()` and was able to follow along with the results. The completefunct is causing it to loop back. However, it is still only deleting two at a time instead of 10 at a time or however many.

Comment: @Easternwind - So, does that mean that you need to fix the `CAMLQuery` string to properly tell it to delete 10 at a time?

Comment: @jfriend00 - The CAMLQuery deletes the number of items I dictated (intStart through intCount) when I remove the looping logic. Which is why I thought that for some reason my loop logic was stepping on itself. Question, is there a way for me to not run the loop until the last batch has processed? Is there something similar to the `$(document).ready()` I could use?

Comment: @Easternwind - I added some comments to the end of my answer about your CAMLQuery parameters.

Comment: @jFriend00; I was able to get it working with some adjustments. Thank you again for you help. I really appreciate it.